# oledb command not fetching values

Tags: ms-access, oledbcommand

through following query i trying to merge three things `parEmail` , `parEmployeeLogin` , and `parStaffID`

now in the case one is null i get whole NameValue null .

```
SELECT (parFirstname +' '+ parSurname) AS NAME, 
  (parEmail +','+ parEmployeeLogin +','+ parStaffID) AS NameValue 
FROM [tblParticipants] 
where parFirstname Is Not Null 
ORDER BY parFirstname
```

NameValue only have data in it if all three fields have data, it's fetching NAME properly....i am using this to get data out of Access file..what changes should be done in this oledb query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` + anything = `NULL`. You've prevented `partFirstName` from being `NULL` with your `WHERE` clause, but if either of the other two columns is `NULL`, the entire result is `NULL`.

You'll have to either use `IIF` to provide alternate values for `NULL` columns, or change your `WHERE` to handle multiple `NULL` columns. (Untested) query for first option (don't have Access on this machine):

```
SELECT 
  partFirstName + ' ' + IIF(IsNull(parSurName), '<None>', parSurName) as Name,
  IIF(IsNull(parEMail), '<No Mail>', parEMail) + ', ' +
    IIF(IsNUll(parEmployeeLogin), '<No Login>', parEmployeeLogin) + ', ' +
    IIF(IsNull(parStaffID), '<No ID>', parStaffID) as NameValue
FROM 
  [tblParticipants]
WHERE 
  parFirstName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  parFirstname
```